# HTML - Dynamic horizontal navigation with "more" dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to implement a design that calls for a horizontal navigation bar atop a page. There are an unknown number of items that might be in this navigation bar. If the bar runs out of room, the links that overrun are to be stuffed into a "more" dropdown.

Visual:

```
|page                                            |
|nav item 1   nav item 2    nav item 3   MORE v  |
|                                                |
```

Within "more" there would be "nav item 4" and "nav item 5". It would change with screen size.

My idea is to use JavaScript to move the links to the dropdown one at a time until the bounding box for the nav bar is an acceptable size. However, with screen flicker and cross-browser JS issues, this idea makes me a sad panda. Is there a better way? Let me know if you've come across some framework for this sort of thing or a pure CSS-based solution or something that doesn't stink as badly as my idea.

In the meantime, I'll try and convince The Powers That Be to use JUST the dropdown rather than cluttering the screen with inconsistencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/cM7sU/

I know you didn't ask for jQuery, but it makes the code so much shorter. There's nothing in here that couldn't be done without it, though.

You can see how the code works, hopefully -- loop backwards through the menu and see if the vertical offset of the last item is different from that of the first item. If so, shove it under the "More" dropdown and continue the loop; if not, break out of the loop. It's wrapped up in a function that's tied to both the `window.resize` event and the `document.ready` event.

Obviously there's a lot missing from this code, functionality-wise, but it should get you started.

```
function shorterMenu() {
    $('#moreitems').children().unwrap().first().remove();
    $items = $('#menu div');
    $more = $('<div id="moreitems" class="menuitem"></div>');
    for (var i = $items.length; i--;) {
        $this = $items.eq(i);
        if ($this.offset().top > $items.eq(0).offset().top || $more.offset().top > $items.eq(0).offset().top) {
            $('#menu').append($more);
            $more.prepend($this);
        } else {
            i = 0; // end for
        }
    }
    if ($more.children().length) {
        $more.prepend('<div id="more" class="menuitem">More</div>');
    }
}
$(document).ready(shorterMenu);
$(window).resize(shorterMenu);
```

Comment: I didn't ask for jQuery, but that's fine. I recently added it to this project and it has made a lot of things a lot easier; but I'm still a drooling noob with it. I'll have to look up half these methods - but I'll enjoy it. Thanks! +1

Comment: I haven't been able to work on it consistently, but I was eventually able to get something like this to work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wanted it, I have rewritten the original Jquery solution for this from @Blazemonger in vanilla javascript https://jsfiddle.net/xobea9cm/

```
const parser = new DOMParser()

function dealWithMenu(menu) {
   let $items = menu.querySelectorAll('div')
   let $more = parser.parseFromString('<div class="more-items"></div>', 
      'text/html').body.firstChild

    for (var i = $items.length; i--;) {
        let $this = $items[i]

        if ($this.offsetTop > ($items[0]).offsetTop || $more.offsetTop > ($items[0]).offsetTop) {
            menu.appendChild($more)
            $more.insertBefore($this, $more.firstChild)
        } else {
            i = 0
        }
    }
    if ($more.children.length) {
         $more.insertBefore(
             parser.parseFromString('<div id="more" class="more-item menuitem">More</div>', 'text/html').body.firstChild,
             $more.firstChild)
    }
}

function shorterMenu() {
    const moreItems = document.querySelector('.more-items')

    const moreDivs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.more-item'))

    moreDivs.forEach(moreDiv => moreDiv.remove())

    if (moreItems != undefined && moreItems.children && moreItems.children.length > 0) {
        Array.from(moreItems.children).forEach(child => moreItems.parentElement.appendChild(child))
        moreItems.remove()
    }

    const menus = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.menu'))

    menus.forEach(dealWithMenu)
}

let throttled = false
const delay = 100

shorterMenu()
window.addEventListener('resize', () => shorterMenu())
```

Answer (score -3):

This can be done purely in css (google css drop down menus and you'll find lots of tutorials) if you need more flexibility and are worried about cross browser support then Jquery will work well for this sort of thing .

Hope that helps.

Comment: "Google it" isn't exactly the response I was hoping for. I've already found plenty of frameworks that implement the actual dropdown; I am looking for a solution that populates items across the nav bar and then puts any overflow into said dropdown, without getting into any javascript.

Comment: this reply doesn't attempt to answer the question